# Excel Forumula - How count last 7 cell in a column?

Tags: excel

I would like to get help on how to write a formula that would count the values in the last 7 cells of my column.

Is someone can help me on this ?

thanks

Comment: Why? The answer is 7, isn't it?

Comment: We need more information if you want us to help. Some code or an example of what you mean would be good.

Comment: My bad, the 'VALUES' in the last 7 cells. If my column contain 10k cells, would like to know the total of the last 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the most optimal solution, however, it should work to sum up the values of the last 7 cells in a given column (in my case, column A):
It assume no blank cells in the list ...

```
=SUM(OFFSET($A$1,COUNTA(A:A)-1,0,-7,1))
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, can you explain a bit why espacially the -1,0,-7,-1 and the Offset part ?

Comment: COUNTA helps id how many rows you have in that column. A blank cell will mess this up. OFFSET gives us a manufactured range, specifically, we're after a range, representing the last 7 rows. So if we have 10 rows. A1 is the first, so we need to "shift down" 9 rows. (1+9 = 10). So the COUNTA gives us 10, we're at 1, 1+10-1 = 10.  the 0, is the column offset. We're already in the col we want, so no change. -7 : you want 7 rows. since we id the bottom row, we have to count UP 7 rows. the final 1 is for width 1 column